# Why is VisualSVN server rewriting my URL?

Tags: svn, apache, visualsvn, reverse-proxy, visualsvn-server

I've installed VisualSVN server on a company machine. Its (intranet) URL is **http://myhost:12321/svn**.

On the same machine there is an Apache which we use as a reverse proxy. There are several other servers on the same machine (Apache, Tomcat), which are made available to the outside using the reverse proxy.

For instance we have a Redmine stack, served internally through **http://myhost:32123/redmine**, which is mapped through the reverse proxy like (conf/rproxy2.conf snippet):

> ```
> ProxyPass /redmine http://myhost:32123/redmine
>
> ProxyPassReverse /redmine http://myhost:32123/redmine
> ```

This works, Redmine is available at **http://my.external.address/redmine**.

When I try to do the same for VisualSVN:

> ```
> ProxyPass /svn http://myhost:12321/svn
>
> ProxyPassReverse /svn http://myhost:12321/svn
> ```

when a user goes to **http://my.external.address/svn**, he gets redirected to **http://myhost:12321/svn**, which ofcourse doesn't work.

Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with ProxyPass because it will give the client a 301 (moved permanently) so the browser will cache that response for a long time.  Try using a different browser or clearing your cache between config changes.